# "what with" use

Tags: phrases, word-usage

Example: His sweet tooth finally got the better of him, what with all the confections surrounding him.

Sounds awkward, but is it correct usage?

Comment: Correct usage. **What** there is emphatic / exclamatory.

Answer (score 2):

It's not awkward and it's correct usage.

[**OED**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/what):
**what with**
Because of (used usually to introduce several causes of something):
*What with the drought and the neglect, the garden is in a sad condition.*
*Here's a category that's heating up, what with all the new developments this year.*

In your sentence it means that the guy finally gave in to his desire for sweet food, *because* there were many confections at his disposal.